# Sign-in and Sign-up Authentication Implementation Issues using xamarin.forms and Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xaml, authentication, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement Sign-in & Sign-up Authentication using Firebase with Xamarin.Forms and I am having the following errors:

1. In the Android Project, it is complaining about this line (public class FirebaseAuthenticator : IFirebaseAuthenticator) in the MainActivity.cs as follows: (Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IFirebaseAuthenticator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))
2. In the iOS Project, it is complaining about this line (public class FirebaseAuthenticator : IFirebaseAuthenticator) in the AppDelegate.cs as follows: (Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IFirebaseAuthenticator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

This is my AppShell.cs, where I defined the shared code:

```
using AbuseAlert.Views;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AbuseAlert
{
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ItemDetailPage), typeof(ItemDetailPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(NewItemPage), typeof(NewItemPage));
    }

    private async void OnMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//LoginPage");
    }
}
}

namespace AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication
{
 public interface IFirebaseAuthenticator
{
    Task<string> SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(string email, string password);
    Task<string> SignUpWithEmailPasswordAsync(string email, string password);
    Task ForgotPasswordAsync(string email);
}
}
```

This is the MainActivity.cs in the Android Project, where the first error occurs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using MediaManager;
using Android;
using Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer.Android;
using LibVLCSharp.Forms.Shared;
using Android.Content;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AbuseAlert.Droid.Authentication.Firebase;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FirebaseAuthenticator))]

namespace AbuseAlert.Droid
{
 [Activity(Label = "AbuseAlert", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]


public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static FirebaseAuth Auth;

    public event EventHandler<ActivityResultEventArgs> ActivityResult = delegate { };
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
        LibVLCSharpFormsRenderer.Init();
        InitFirebaseAuth(); //Create an instance of FirebaseAuth

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio }, 1);
        }

        FormsVideoPlayer.Init();
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        ActivityResult(this, new ActivityResultEventArgs
        {
            RequestCode = requestCode,
            ResultCode = resultCode,
            Data = data
        });

        //base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //AuthenticationAgentContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationAgentContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void InitFirebaseAuth()
    {

        var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetProjectId("abusealert-53b22") //YOUR_PROJECT_ID")
            .SetApplicationId("1:883750321469:android:65f90ffae4042a695b1954") //YOUR_APPLICATION_ID")
            .SetApiKey("AIzaSyBk_4DWo-bMvrqOI2FfsfuK61HEF-OY3J8") //YOUR_FIREBASE_API_KEY")
            .SetDatabaseUrl("https://abusealert-53b22-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com") //YOUR_DATABASEURL")
            .SetStorageBucket("nam5 (us-central)") //YOUR_STORAGEBUCKET")
            .Build();
        //https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/abusealert-53b22/database/abusealert-53b22-default-rtdb/data/~2F

        var _fireApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

        Auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(_fireApp);
    }

}
}

namespace AbuseAlert.Droid.Authentication.Firebase
{
public class FirebaseAuthenticator : IFirebaseAuthenticator
{
    public async Task<string> LoginWithEmailPasswordAsync(string email, string password)
    {

        var user = await MainActivity.Auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
        var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);

        return token.Token;
    }

    public async Task<string> SignUpWithEmailPasswordAsync(string email, string password)
    {

        var user = await MainActivity.Auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
        var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);
        return token.Token;
    }

    public async Task ConfirmPasswordResetAsync(string code, string newPassword)
    {
        await MainActivity.Auth.ConfirmPasswordResetAsync(code, newPassword);
    }

    public async Task ForgotPasswordAsync(string email)
    {
        await MainActivity.Auth.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync(email);

    }

    public async Task VerifyPasswordResetCodeAsync(string code)
    {
        await MainActivity.Auth.VerifyPasswordResetCodeAsync(code);
    }

}
}
```

This is the AppDelegate.cs file for iOS Project where the 2nd error occurs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AbuseAlert.iOS.Implementations.Auth;
using Foundation;
using MediaManager;
using Octane.Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FirebaseAuthenticator))]

namespace AbuseAlert.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for 
launching the 
// User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
// application events from iOS.
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();

        FormsVideoPlayer.Init();

        Firebase.Core.App.Configure(); 

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
}

namespace AbuseAlert.iOS.Implementations.Auth
{

class FirebaseAuthenticator : IFirebaseAuthenticator
{

    public async Task<string> LoginWithEmailPassword(string email, string password)
    {

        var authDataResult = await Firebase.Auth.Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithPasswordAsync(
            email,
            password);

        return await authDataResult.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> SignupWithEmailPassword(string email, string password)
    {
        var authDataResult = await Firebase.Auth.Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserAsync(
        email,
        password);

        return await authDataResult.User.GetIdTokenAsync();
    }
}
}
```

So what do I need to do to clear these errors?

Answer (score 0):

this is a very basic C# error that is discussed at length in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246)

you've defined `IFirebaseAuthenticator` in the `AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication` namespace

```
namespace AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication
{
  public interface IFirebaseAuthenticator
```

so when you want to use `IFirebaseAuthenticator` elsewhere in your code, you need to tell it which `namespace` to use

```
using AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication;
```

or by fully qualifying the namespace when you use `IFirebaseAuthenticator`

```
AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication.IFirebaseAuthenticator
```

in many cases if you right-click on the error in VS, it will provide suggested fixes that you can select from

Comment: Right-clicking on it in VS 2022, suggested that I reference AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication in the iOS project, which I did. Now the errors have increased. 1. Error CS0535 'FirebaseAuthenticator' does not implement interface member 'IFirebaseAuthenticator.SignUpWithEmailPasswordAsync(string, string)' 2.  'FirebaseAuthenticator' does not implement interface member 'IFirebaseAuthenticator.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(string, string)' 3. 
Error CS0535 'FirebaseAuthenticator' does not implement interface member 'IFirebaseAuthenticator.ForgotPasswordAsync(string)'

Comment: then perhaps you should try the specific fix I suggested

Comment: I did that also (AbuseAlert.Interfaces.FirebaseAuthentication.IFirebaseAuthenticator). It gave the same errors as above.

Comment: again, this is very basic C#.  Your class needs to implement the contract of the interface.  Your interface says you **must** have a method `SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync`, but your class has a method `LoginWithEmailPassword`.  The class DOES NOT match the interface.

Comment: When I right_clicked on it after using your suggestion, VS suggested that it needs to implement interface and when I asked it to go ahead, it generated 3 tasks within the namespace in the iOS project and this is one of the tasks:         public Task<string> SignUpWithEmailPasswordAsync(string email, string password)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } The error has disappeared but I am not sure this has solved the issue because the original github code i used did not have these tasks.

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes, thanks Jason. That particular error has gone as you suggested. I replaced LoginWithEmailPassword with SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync and that was that. However, it is throwing up another error on this line [var token = await user.User.GetIdTokenAsync(false);]. Error CS1061 'FirebaseUser' does not contain a definition for 'GetIdTokenAsync' and no accessible extension method 'GetIdTokenAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'FirebaseUser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Any suggestion?